# Primefaces <p:ajax update...> crashes form

Tags: java

I have a problem when I select an item from a component and when updating another component, it stops working. The strange thing is that with  the application works correctly but with  it breaks.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="#{bundle.columnas}" layout="grid" id="panel">  

        <p:outputLabel for="provincia" value="Provincia *" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="provincia"
                         value="#{inmuebleBacking.provincia}"                          
                         converter="provinciaConverter">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Una Provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{provinciaBacking.findAllProvincias()}" var="prov" itemLabel="#{prov.provinciaNombre}" />
            <p:ajax update="ciudad" listener="#{inmuebleBacking.provinciaSelecionada()}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="ciudad" value="Ciudad *" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="ciudad"
                         value="#{inmuebleBacking.ciudad}"                          
                         converter="ciudadConverter" 
                         required="true">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Una Ciudad" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{inmuebleBacking.ciudades}" var="ciudad" itemLabel="#{ciustrong textdad.ciudadNombre} cp: #{ciudad.cp}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

BackingBeans

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "inmuebleBacking")
public class InmuebleBacking {

    @EJB
    private CiudadDAO ciudadDAO;
    private List<Ciudad> ciudades;

    public void provinciaSelecionada() {
        Inmueble inmueble = (Inmueble) getEntity();
        ciudades = ciudadDAO.findAllNamedBy("Ciudad.findByProvinciaId", "provinciaId", inmueble.getProvincia().getId());}
```

[SCREENSHOTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZroEY.jpg)

Comment: No exceptions from Java and no errors in the browser's console?

Comment: As @AlexR said, if there is any, please add the whole error stack to the question.

Comment: There is no error in the console glassfish and also in the browser log